# How to refresh the body in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to refresh the Body section in SwiftUI. I want to do this as people can change the location of where the weather should be and I want the user to be able to refresh and see the new location's weather without closing the app and re-opening.
I have tried setting a @State variable but this doesn't work either.
Here is the code:

```
var body: some View {
    let test = TestCall2(string: "a")
    ZStack {
        
        BackgroundView(isNight: $isNight)
        VStack {
            let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
            let country = defaults.string(forKey: "Country") ?? "England"
            let city = defaults.string(forKey: "City") ?? "London"
            let name = "\(city), \(country)"
            CityName(name: name).id("yes")
            
            
            MainTemp(weatherIcon:
                        isNight ? "moon.stars.fill" : "cloud.sun.fill", temp: Int(data.temp.temp)).id("yes")
            
                
            HStack(spacing: 20) {
                WeatherDayView(dayOfWeek: TestCall(string: "Mon"),
                               imageName: CalledOnceLoaded(string: "cloud.sun.fill"),
                               temperature: 12)
                WeatherDayView(dayOfWeek: "Tue",
                               imageName: "cloud.fill",
                               temperature: 14)
                WeatherDayView(dayOfWeek: "Wed",
                               imageName: "cloud.sun.rain.fill",
                               temperature: 17)
                WeatherDayView(dayOfWeek: "Thur",
                               imageName: "cloud.heavyrain.fill",
                               temperature: 8)
                WeatherDayView(dayOfWeek: "Fri",
                               imageName: "sun.max.fill",
                               temperature: 19)
            }.id("yes")
            Spacer()
            let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

            let country = defaults.string(forKey: "Country") ?? "England"
            let city = defaults.string(forKey: "City") ?? "London"
            Button {
                getData(city: city, country: country)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.change.toggle()
                    print(self.change)
                }
                
            } label: {
                FormattedButton(text: "Refresh", textColor: .blue, backgroundColor: .white)
            }
            
            
            Spacer()
            

            
        }
    }
    
}
```

[Here](https://youtu.be/7QirS-1gPqQ) is a video of my trying to refresh it.

Comment: You refresh the view by updating properties that are wrapped as `@State`, `@StateObject` or similar. If you don’t know about them then I suggest you do some research

Comment: Where does the data come from? If it's from a class have you tried to conform it to ObservableObject and use a @StateObject? Don't forget to make your variables Published using @Published!

Comment: The above is great advice. In addition, you haven't provided enough code in your example to diagnose why it isn't working. When posting here, try to include a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a fix! It is a bit hacky but it works. I have a bool called isNight which enables night mode and it is called in the body section. To make it update, I just toggled it twice and nothing happens to night mode but the body updates. Hope this helped people